# Prepared statement PDO returning 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
var_dump($query) = string(133) "SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM movies t1, releases t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.movieid AND title LIKE ? AND LOCATE (?, subtitles) ORDER BY added DESC"

var_dump($qqq) = array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "'%brian%'" [1]=> string(9) "'English'" }

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute($qqq)){
    echo $stmt->rowCount();
}else{
    echo "Not";
}
```

This returns 0, the query works but no result.
If I run "`SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM movies t1, releases t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.movieid AND title LIKE '%brian%' AND LOCATE ('English', subtitles) ORDER BY added DESC`" in phpmyadmin I get results. I don't know where to look anymore, checked everything that I know.

Comment: Don't quote your variables in `$qqq`. PDO will do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't include the quotes in your arguments. `$qqq` should look like this:

```
$qqq = array("%brian%", "English");
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. Don't know how I missed the quotes.